# Why is Safari printing this page with gigantic text as if it's zoomed in?

Tags: html, css

When you try to print this recipe: https://ph.dev.dquinn.net/easy-vegan-pho/, everything appears zoomed in, so the recipe is like 6 pages long, only in Safari browsers.

Here is a link to the result in Safari: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY20P.jpg

If you look at it in Chrome, it's 2 pages long. What's the deal?

I'm not sure where to even start to debug this. Fonts are rendered as vw from px via a SASS function. I'm applying the below print styles to hide elements on that page.

```
/*
utilities
*/
@import "utility/**/*";

.recipe .recipe-content .recipe-ins .state-marker i,
.recipe-ins-paging,
.recipe .recipe-header,
.header-main,
body.is-recipe .addthis_toolbox,
body.is-recipe .comments-area,
body.is-recipe [data-module="panel"],
body.is-recipe [data-module="cta"],
body.is-recipe .recipe .recipe-header .button,
body.is-recipe [data-module="feature"],
body.is-recipe .column-wrap.tinymce {
    display: none !important;
}

.recipe .recipe-notes.is-closed .recipe-notes-desc {
    display: block;
}

.recipe {
    padding-top: 0;
}

.printonly {

    &.recipe-print-heading {
        @include font-size(48px);
        display: block;
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 20px auto 0;
        position: static;
        text-align: center;
    }

    &.main-logo {
        max-width: 300px;
        margin: 50px auto;
        display: block;
    }
}
```